# android MediaExtractor MediaCodec seek

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, seek, mediaextractor

Question again, guys.

I use MediaExtractor and MediaCodec to play MP4 file on android device. Everything works fine until  I try to add Extractor.seekto().

If I just play mp3 file with my player,seeking functions well. However, when I try it with MP4 file, the video is not updated. I tried to debug the code, finding out that the   `mPlayerExtractor.getSampleTrackIndex()` always returns 1 (Refer to the audio track).

But I do not know how to fix it.

I cannot put all my code here. So please give me some advise first. Thanks a lot.

Update: I can seek backward for both mp4 file and webm file. If I seek forward with webm file, The video starts to play after the same time of jumped time of the seeking operation. For mp4 file, it just never starts again.

Comment: What does "video is not updated" mean?  Are you using `SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC`?

Comment: @fadden I mean the audio goes to the right time I'm seeking while the video does not. The video just stopped at the current time. BTW, I use the surfaceview to render  the output.

Comment: @fadden yes, I used the SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC. Here is my code 'mPlayerExtractor.seekTo((long)progress*1000, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);' progress is the time in millisecond

Comment: @fadden I saw a lot of your posts, and I think you know the MediaCodec and MediaExtractor qutie well. So do you get any idea about another problem troubling me. I post it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127046/why-mediaextractor-gettrackcount-return-0-in-android-4-4-2. Many thanks

Comment: Do you have two separate classes to handle audio and video, or it is just one and determine inside if it is audio or video? In second case, are the threads properly synced, is there any global variable to the class that is modified by the other thread? Do you correctly compute the seek point according to current position?