# Why MediaExtractor getTrackCount returns 0 in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, mediaextractor

I ran exactly the same code on:

- Android 4.1.2
- Android 4.2.2
- Android 4.4.2.

It works well on 4.1.2 and 4.2.2, **but NOT on 4.4.2.**

The problem is `MediaExtractor.getTrackCount` returns 0 on 4.4.2 (while it returns the right number on other devices)

Any idea?

I am also facing the very same issue.
Did you got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out where the problem is.
For 4.4.2, u got to add permission in the AndroidManifest.xml about write external storage if you play local file.
here is the code