# Why is MediaExtractor returning 0 for getTrackCount() on Android O?

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo, mediaextractor

I am trying to create a custom video player in Android Oreo. After migrating from L, the extractor is returning 0 when getting trackCount.  When the file is inserted in assets, it is working. There is no error on the opening extractor, only the log is showing no tracks found.

I added all permissions for writing and reading storage both from code and in the xml.

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
    try {
extractor.setDataSource(
"/sdcard/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4" );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int numTracks = extractor.getTrackCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2` in `build.gradle` and `gradle-6.9-all.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`. Please refer to below link: [Why MediaExtractor getTrackCount returns 0 in android 4.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127046/why-mediaextractor-gettrackcount-returns-0-in-android-4-4-2)