# Seekbar not updating for Mediaplayer Android Lollipop API Level 21

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using a surfaceview to play video and mediaplayer seekto updates the sound and video as well. But with lollipop, when I am trying to using seekto only the audio changes but the video remains at the same position. Can anyone help why Lollipop is causing this issue?

P.S. On versions before lollipop, same code works perfectly.
.
**Edit**: Observed the same behavior in Facebook while seeking video and also in MX player. But in MX player on changing from HW to SW encoder seeking works fine. How to fix it in my code?

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromuser) {
    long duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
    long newposition = (duration * progress) / 1000L;
    mPlayer.seekTo((int) newposition);
    Log.d(TAG, "progress changed");
    // mPlayer.setDisplay();
    // mPlayer.start(); 
}
```

Fragment :

```
    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.surfView);
    frame = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.videoSurfaceContainer);
    vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
    vidHolder.addCallback(this);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    playVideo();

}


public void playVideo() {

    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
    VideosModel model = null;

        model = videosList.get(videoPosition);


    videoTitle = model.getVideoTitle();
    tvTitle.setText(videoTitle);

    try {
        // mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
        mediaPlayer
                .setDataSource(getActivity(), Uri.parse(model.getPath()));
        tryToGetAudioFocus();
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122394/android-mediaextractor-mediacodec-seek sounds similar, though that was using lower-level APIs.

Comment: If anyone could suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by disabling Nu player in Developer options. Everything works fine now.